# How to Click hidden span[role="checkbox"] in selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I can click hidden span tag checkbox using playwright codegen.

Here is the code:

```
page.frame_locator("iframe[role=\"presentation\"]").locator("span[role=\"checkbox\"]").click()
```

But How Can I do the same thing using selenium?

I am trying this but It's not working for me

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//iframe[@role='presentation']").find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@role='checkbox']").click()
```

Could anyone please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Can you share a page you working on?

Comment: Here is the page link.  https://www.google.com/sorry/index?continue=https://www.google.com/search%3Fq%3DCan%2BDogs%2BSwim%3F%26num%3D10%26lr%3Dlang_en%26hl%3Den%26cr%3DUS&hl=en&q=EgSgypGAGPzHxZgGIhDgZHgxkrJbOHI66Q4Gx82XMgFy

Comment: I can't find the element you mentioned there, there is no any iframe and no checkboxes at all there...

Comment: Oh! I got this from playwright codegen. And yes, These are not available in page source. By the way, Did you check the page front end? Is there any way to click on "I am not a robot" checkbox using selenium?

Comment: There is no any `"I am not a robot` there as well and this would be a separate issue, how to resolve captcha with selenium. Specifically I don't know how to do that.